# No funciona mi script. No encuentro el error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He intentado hacer un sencillo registro de clientes y clientes potenciales en dos hojas por separado. Le agregué un script para que al pinchar sobre una casilla de verificación en la hoja POTENCIALES, este registro se copie en la hoja de clientes y se borre automáticamente del registro anterior. Adicionalmente quería que omita las primeras dos columnas y copie el resto (la primera columna es una enumeracion automática tambien con script y la segunda columna es la casilla de verificación).

En la hoja CLIENTES tengo una primera columna con codificación automática y luego siguen los datos que deberian copiarse. El orden de las columnas es el mismo y las variables me las reconoce pero no el rango y no sé si es un problema de configuración.

Quizás sea útil mencionar que tengo un script `OnEdit` que ejecuta esta y otras *macros* más y tiene un activador al editar la hoja de cálculo. Dejo el código a ver si alguien encentra el problema porque ya  lo revisé como unas 10 veces y nada.

```
function moverClientes() {
  var archivo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = archivo.getSheetByName("POTENCIALES");
  var hojaDestino = archivo.getSheetByName("CLIENTES");
  var celdaActiva = hojaOrigen.getActiveCell();
  var filaActiva = celdaActiva.getRow();
  var colActiva = celdaActiva.getColumn();
  var valor = celdaActiva.getValue();

 if(filaActiva>=2 && colActiva==2 && valor=="VERDADERO"){
  var rangoOrigen = hojaOrigen.getRange(filaActiva,3,1,hojaOrigen.getLastColumn());
  var rangoDestino = hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino.getLastRow()+1,2);

  // Copiar y eliminar fila 
   rangoOrigen.copyTo(rangoDestino)
   hojaOrigen.deleteRow(filaActiva)
   hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino)
  }
}
```

Comment: Falta agregar detalles como el número de columnas máximas y números de filas del rango de datos sí como indicar si se ha registrado un error o es simplemente que no hace lo que estás esperando.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es verificar si tus checkboxes están configurados con valores booleanos o con valores tipo texto.

---

Me parece que tu código tiene varios problemas.

1. Eficiencia: No estás aprovechando el objeto evento . Más información en [Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
   Este objeto incluye la propiedades `range` y `value` (este último sólo se incluye cuando se edita una celda). Además el objeto referenciado por range incluye las propiedades `rowStart`, `rowEnd`, `columnStart` y `columnEnd`.
2. El `rangoOrigen` no está apropiadamente especificado
   Esto porque los últimos dos parámetros se refieren a la cantidad de filas y cantidad de columnas, en lugar de `hojaOrigen.getLastColumn()` se debería indicar `hojaOrigen.getLastColumn() - 2` porque la columna de inicio es la 3.
3. El valor devuelto de una celda con un casilla de verificación puede ser complicado. De forma prederminada se asignan los valores booleanos `VERDADERO` y `FALSO` pero se pueden personalizar para usar valores de texto `"VERDADERO"` y `"FALSO"`. En el primer caso `getValue()` va a devolver `true` y `false` respectivamente pero si los has personalizado te devolverá el valor correspondiente.
4. Eficiencia. La última línea (`hojaDestino.getRange(hojaDestino)`) un rango pero no se hace nada con este.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta esto:

Cambia

```
valor=="VERDADERO"
```

por

```
valor==true
```

A mi me funciono así